# <script defer> not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to `defer` my script execution because it is not important that it executes before the page is rendered. However, it is not working as I understand it.

According to [this article](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) (and others like it), if I use `defer` then the execution order is preserved. However, when using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) I am seeing a different behaviour. My script files look like so:-

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript">hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Now as I understand it they should execute in order which is unlike the behaviour of `async`. However, I get the following error in Chrome (version 44.0.2403.157).

[image]

If I remove the `defer` attributes it works as expected. What am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: wouldnt this only work if `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()` was also in an external file (and the loading of that file was "defer'd")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The defer attribute has been browser specific http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer (thanks to atmd)

> The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src
>   attribute is not present.

Check your second case.