# Javascript defer is not working for FilePond

Tags: html

I am using filepond to upload files to my web application. I am using all the scripts in the head tag using defer but they are not loading the scripts. But when I am placing them in the body tag after the input file type they are loading correctly and filepond is working. Also when I am using defer for the same scripts in the body, filepond stops working. I am provinding the template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <input type="file" class="filepond">

        <!-- <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
        <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.js"></script>
        <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-resize/dist/filepond-plugin-image-resize.js"></script>
        <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
        <script>
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageResize);
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileEncode);
            const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
            const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
            FilePond.parse(document.body);
        </script> -->
        <title>Mybrary</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <input type="file" class="filepond"> -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-resize/dist/filepond-plugin-image-resize.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
        <script>
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageResize);
            FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileEncode);
            const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
            const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
            FilePond.parse(document.body);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone please tell me why defer isn't working?

(P.S. - I am using ejs as view template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defer attribute has been browser-specific http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer (thanks to atm)

The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present.

Check your second case. 
check this URL

> **[<script defer> not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225624/script-defer-not-working-as-expected)**